# Three unhelpful clues

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

First clue:

```
I'm no laughing matter.
But something there is that doesn't love my brother,
so you dug deep to create me.
```

Second clue:

```
I'm food.
I'm popular in Morocco.
But I'm even bigger in Israel.
```

Third clue:

```
I'm a special kind of armament,
which will help you propel an arm,
better than just your arm.
```

The question:

**What capital city am I?**

First hint:

> The three clues are independent riddles; each has a different (and topically unrelated) answer, which is different from the answer to the question.

Second hint (for the third clue):

> This is a Nahuatl-derived word.

Comment: Just to make sure, is the second line of the first clue exactly meant as written? It seems lime you perhaps meant to switch 'is' and 'there'

Comment: The word order is correct. Or, rather, faithful.

Comment: Pretty good puzzle. I never did get clue 1, can you elaborate?

Comment: @John You got the gist of line 2; it also describes *why* [the thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ha-ha) exists, kind of. Line 1 is a play on words from the name (and quite accurate, if you walked into one), and line 3 describes how the thing is made.

Comment: Ah ha! Hadn't heard of a ha-ha. Nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the third clue, given the hint, must surely be

> atlatl

(which I thought was the only Nahuatl word I knew, until I actually started looking for others; but none of the others I found seems to have the right sort of meaning).

And since (per John's answer) it seems that the answer to the second is probably

> couscous

and, aha!, the first one must be

> haha.

So perhaps the capital city we're looking for is

> Pago Pago.

Comment: ** Good Stuff! **

Comment: I actually have a tab open in the same browser window as this clue with your suggested city (based on suspicion from answer 2 and the way the puzzle was framed), but couldn't figure out either the first or last clue to confirm.  Just FYI, Israeli couscous is actually physically bigger than other types. ;)

Comment: How did you get from the clues to the conclusion of "Pago Pago"? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Kirex, if clue 1 was 'haha', and clue 2 is 'couscous', and clue 3 is 'atlatl', then you're looking for a city that is a repeated name. So, Pago Pago fits. Note that the OP mentioned that the clues were 'topically' unrelated. So, their repeating pattern was how they were related.

Answer (score 4):

Oy, vey! Is it:

> Back to Jerusalem?

I'm no laughing matter.
But something there is that doesn't love my brother,
so you dug deep to create me.

> Possibly a progression of Wailing [Wall] > Frost's [Mending Wall](http://www.bartleby.com/104/64.html) > [Mending] Well.

Second clue:

I'm food.
I'm popular in Morocco.
But I'm even bigger in Israel.

> Couscous, or [ptitim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptitim) made from semolina.

Third clue:

I'm a special kind of armament,
which will help you propel an arm,
better than just your arm.

> Most to least likely: sling, sling-shot, bow (as in arrow), and finally RPG :) As in David and Goliath, fought in the Valley of Elah, modern Israel?

Comment: You've got the second clue correct, and you are of course on the right track with the first one (but this is a closer 'brother'). I'm rephrasing the third clue.

Comment: @Sneftel, Ah. I think I now have the third, just trying to put it together.

Comment: With just two clues, you should be able to see the commonality.

Comment: @Sneftel, I'm pretty sure I still don't have it, but I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Not there yet. You're on the right track with the third one. But there's no theme to this puzzle.